# Colorir Desenho em Canvas e Aumentar Área de Pintura

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Eu tenho um tipo de entretenimento numa página onde escolho um desenho que é colocado dentro de um `canvas` para colorir.

Eu já tenho o pincel e as cores. Mas eu quero algo que faça a função do balde que pinta uma área inteira.

Clica no balde, depois clica em uma parte do desenho e pinta a região que foi clicada.

Tem um site que tem isso:

http://desportos.colorir.com/outros-desportos/judo-1.html

Tentei entender o código fonte, mas não consegui achar a função.

Alguém tem ideia do como posso fazer ? Só o início.

O plugin que estou usando é esse:

http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código que você tem até o momento, ou qual PLUGIN JQUERY está utilizando.

Comment: Editei o poste, Paulo Hard Disk.

Comment: Sugestão de pesquisa: flood fill

Comment: Olá. Como já comentaram, seria bom você colocar o código que está fazendo para que alguém possa ajudar onde estiver algum erro. Do jeito que a pergunta está, você está basicamente pedindo pra alguém fazer o código pra vc (e esse não é o foco deste site).

Answer (score 1):

O plugin que você está utilizando não da suporte para o que você quer, ele ainda está na versão 0.0.1.

O Máximo que você pode fazer é aumentar a área de ação do pincel. pintar uma do desenho no canvas com BALDE requer uma quantidade grande de código.

Da uma olhada no Google, tem vários plugins que podem te ajudar melhor.

https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bucket%20paint%20jquery

Esse aqui parece bem rico e mesmo assim não tem o que você precisa.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-for-Simple-Drawing-Surface-wPaint/

Comment: Pelo que andei pesquisando tem a ver com manipulação de pixels. O site que coloquei na minha pergunta tem dois arquivos: **painterGame.min.js** e **painterMobile.js**. Tentei usá-los, mas me mostra um erro de script.

Comment: Poderia postar qual é o erro?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null`

Comment: pode mandar a linha de código que da o erro?

Comment: `btnPincel.className="",`, no Chrome mostra isso.

Comment: tnPincel não foi instânciado. por isso o erro.